# How to (re-)open "Running Devices" window in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I know it is a simple and even silly question, but for the life of me I cannot find it out by myself - or by googling:

How do I reopen the "Running Devices" window in Android Studio that shows the emulated devices currently running, once I have closed the window for whatever reason? I am referring to the window in the screenshot below. Many thanks in advance!

[image: Example]